# Matlab: Cut Vector at missing values and create new vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to write a Matlab script. 
In my example I have a vector A=[1 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 21]

Now I want to cut the vector automatically at the points where a number is missing(here the numbers 2, 6, 12, 18 are missing).

As a result I want to have the vectors [1] and [3 4 5] and [7 8 9 10 11] and [13 14 15 16 17] and [19 20 21]. So as you can see the new vectors have different lenghts.

I thought about using a for loop, but I am not sure how to write these new vectors.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner with `diff`, `cumsum` & `accumarray` -

```
out = accumarray(cumsum([0 ; diff(A(:))~=1])+1,A(:),[],@(x) {x})
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     3     4     5     7     8     9    10    ... 
            11    13    14    15    16    17    19    20    21
>> celldisp(out)
out{1} =
     1
out{2} =
     3
     4
     5
out{3} =
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
out{4} =
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
out{5} =
    19
    20
    21
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach:

```
s = [find(diff(A(:).')>1) numel(A)]; %'// detect where consecutive difference exceeds 1
s = [s(1) diff(s)]; %// sizes of groups
result = mat2cell(A(:).', 1, s); %'// split into cells according to those sizes
```

In your example, this gives

```
>> celldisp(result)
result{1} =
     1
result{2} =
     3     4     5
result{3} =
     7     8     9    10    11
result{4} =
    13    14    15    16    17
result{5} =
    19    20    21
```

---

Another approach (computes group sizes differently):

```
s = diff([0 sum(bsxfun(@lt, A(:), setdiff(1:max(A(:).'), A(:).')), 1) numel(A)]);
result = mat2cell(A(:).', 1, s);
```